# Data validation using regular expressions in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using the below date/time format in gSheets:

**01 Apr at 11:00**

I wonder whether it is possible to use Data Validation (or any other function) to report error (add the small red triangle to the corner of the cell) when the format differs in any way.

Possible values in the given format:

- 01 -> any number between 01-31 (but not "1", there must be the leading zero)
- *space*
- Apr -> 3 letters for month (Jan, Feb, Mar... Dec)
- *space*
- at
- *space*
- 11 -> hours in 24h format (00, 01...23)
- :
- 00 -> minutes (00, 01,...59)

Is there any way to validate that the cell contains "text/data" exactly in the above mentioned format?

Comment: Those might help other users:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85747
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92665/using-regex-in-google-sheets-data-validation

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this is using Regular Expression and "regexmatch()" function in Google Sheets. For the given example, I made the below regular expression:

```
[0-3][0-9] (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) at [0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]
```

***Process:***

- Select range of cells to be validated
- Go to Data > Data Validation
- Under Criteria select "Own pattern is" (not sure the exact translation used in EN)
- Paste: `=regexmatch(to_text(K4); "[0-3][0-9] (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) at [0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]")`
- Make sure that instead of K4 in "to_text(K4)" there is a upper-left cell from the selected range
- Save

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the formula for data validation:

`=not(iserror(SUBSTITUTE(A1," at","")*1))*(len(A1)=15)*(right(A1,2)*1<61)`

- `not(iserror(SUBSTITUTE(A1," at","")*1))` checks all statemant is legal date
- `(len(A1)=15)` checks dates are entered with 2 digits
- `(right(A1,2)*1<61)` cheks too much minutes, for some reason `01 Apr at 11:99` is a legal date..

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the range of fields, where you need the data validation to occur to.
2. Press on -> Data -> Data validation
3. For "Criteria" select "Custom formula is"
4. Enter the following in the textfield next to "Custom formula is":
   =regexmatch(Tablename!B2; "^[a-z_]*$")

Where as "Tablename" should be replaced by the table name and "B2" should be replaced by the first cell of the range.

Inside the "" you enter then your regex-expression. Here this would allow only small letters and underscores.

Using the to_text() function additionally didn't work for me. So you should maybe avoid it in order to make sure, that it works.

5. Press save